# processes that start when running .net console apllication won't close

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have noticed a weird issue when running a console program (that I have written) from the console itself, instead of using VS's Start option.

When I run the program, there will be multiple (2-3) processes that are (supposedly) running my program (they have the same name), although I can only see one instance running on the desktop.

When I close this instance, one of these processes also ends but the others don't and I can't close them, no matter what I try (task manager, taskkil). The only way I can close them is restarting the computer.

The programs I write don't do anything special, and it's the same situation even with the most trivial "hello, world!" program.

Note that this only happens when I run something I have written and I run it from outside VS.

In any other case the issue is not present (as far as I can tell). I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate 32 bit on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 32 bit.

Comment: This should definitely not happen. Let's see if I understood correctly: a simple `Console.WriteLine("Hello world");` program gets executed many times if you run it from the console?

Comment: Can you give the names of the processes? One of them is probably the "Hosting Process" which will be the name of your exe with "vshost" appended to it. You can read how to disable it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx)

Comment: @Quantic that should not happen if running the exe from the console (not from visual studio)

Comment: Yes, it happens even with a simple "hello, world!" program. When I run it from outside VS then about 3 processes start with the same name. Say, the compiled programs name is hello.exe. Then i will have 3 processes with the name hello.exe (but with different PIDs), neither of them having vshost in their name (there are no issues with that process). All three of them have the exact name of the program file i'm running. When My hello.exe stops running then one of the processes ends, but the other 2 stays and i can't close them unless i restart the machine.

Comment: My question boils down to this: is this an issue with My Windows installation or with My VS installation and can I fix it without reinstalling (at least the OS).

Comment: How are you running the program? Double clicking in Explorer? Opening cmd.exe and typing in the full path to the exe and hitting 'enter'? Can you put your entire "hello world" example in your post so we can see your actual example code? Do you not have another machine you can copy the .exe to and test to verify it's not your windows or environment that's messed up? Maybe you have "single click" enabled in windows, and also your mouse is broken, so when you click to open the program it's triple clicking to open 3, and also you have some file access in there so 2 instances fight and deadlock..

Comment: @user100939 this is a very wild guess, but can you check if your exe changes sizes when you run it, and/or if the path of the other exe processes is actually the same as the original one? Might be some malware infection in your system (again, wild guessing, but it's so strange it's worth checking)